# How do I count the number of child collection's items using LINQ Method Syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, methods, syntax, count

Let's say I have a schema, representing Question entities. Each question can be voted up, voted down or, of course, not voted at all - just like here in StackOverflow. I want to get the number of voteups for a given user.

```
int number = (from q in userDbContext.Questions
              from qv in q.QuestionVotes
              where qv.IsVoteUp
              select qv).Count();
```

I want to write the same query, but using Method Syntax. How do I do this with the same example?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
userDbContext.Questions.SelectMany(x => x.QuestionVotes).Count(x => x.IsVoteUp);
```

Answer (score 5):

This `LINQ` query demonstrates how to do that using **3 level structure `tree` > `branch` > `leaf` as an example**.

So the code below gives you the **number of the leaves from all branches of all trees** (all or only colored with the given color):

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int CountAllLeafsOn(List<Tree> trees, string сolor = null)
    {
        // Count the leafs (all from all branches of all trees, or only if they are colored with the provided color)
        return сolor == null 
            ? trees.Sum(tree => tree.Branches.Sum(branch => branch.Leaves.Count)) 
            : trees.Sum(tree => tree.Branches.Sum(branch => branch.Leaves.Count(leaf => leaf.Color.Equals(сolor))));
    }
}

public class Tree
{
    public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public List<Leaf> Leaves { get; set; }
}

public class Leaf
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nicely explained.

Answer (score 4):

It must work:

```
  int number =  userDbContext.Questions
                             .Select(x => x.QuestionVotes.Count(y => y.IsVoteUp))
                             .Sum();
```

It will get the count of filtered child items for each parent. Then `Sum()` will compute the sum of these values.

Answer (score 0):

You can count children using Where like this:

```
foreach (YourCollectionType item in datagrid.Items)
{
     var children = datagrid.ItemsSource.OfType<YourCollectionType>().Where(x => x.Item1 == item.Item1 && x.Item2 == item.Item2 && x.Item3 == item.Item3 && x.Item4 == item.Item4);

     item.Results = children.Count();
     Trace.TraceInformation(item.Results.ToString());

}
```